# How is partial application working here?

Tags: haskell, syntax

```
> map (++ "!") ["a", "b", "c"]
["a!","b!","c!"]
> (++) "!" "a"
"!a"
```

These two lines don't make sense to me. When using `++` in `map`, it seems like the first parameter is appended to the second, but in the second list it's the other way around. How does Haskell reason about the behavior in the `map` function?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `(++ "!")` is a bit of special syntax called an [operator section](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Section_of_an_infix_operator). It's partially-applying the *second* parameter of the infix operator, whereas `(++) "!"` works like normal partial application and is applying the first parameter.

You can also do the same thing with regular functions used infix-style with backticks: `` (`map` [1..3]) `` is equivalent to `(\f -> map f [1..3])`.

It seems odd because it is, it's a special-case extra feature that's in there just because it's darn useful.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `("!" ++)` is legal too, which is the same as `\x -> "!" ++ x`.

Comment: @Antal: In Haskell 98, yes. But for performance reasons, GHC does just `(++) "!"` instead, which might trweak something like expression caching a bit.

Comment: True, which also enables you to use postfix operators with that syntax (though I think that requires a GHC option); however, for explaining the concept, defining one confused thing in terms of what it's being confused with probably isn't helpful :-)

Answer (score 2):

The partial application `(++ "!")` is identical to `(\x -> x ++ "!")`. In other words, the expression `(++ "!")` is smart enough to know that the `"!"` is the second argument to `(++)`. It knows this because it knows that `++` is an infix operator. In the second expression, `(++) "!" "a"` is identical to `"!" ++ "a"`, and does what you'd expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
map (++ "!) ["a", "b", "c"]
```

is equivalent to

```
["a" ++ "!", "b" ++ "!", "c" ++ "!"]
```

And

```
(++) "!" "a"
```

is equivalent to

```
"!" ++ "a"
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: But if `(++) "!" "a"` is equivalent to `"!" ++ "a"`, then why isn't it mapping the list to the second parameter? Is this just a special case for infix functions?

Comment: It has to do with how map treats things. Map will concatenate always the the list's element to the "!", not the other way around.

Comment: It doesn't really have anything to do with `map`. `(++ "!") "a"` is equivalent to `("a" ++ "!")`.

Comment: You are probably right cam. My Haskell knowledge is not that great.